# ReferenceError: message is not defined for my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, undefined

I was trying to do a! Clear for the discord bot and this error appears:

```
  const args = message.content.slice (prefix.lenght) .split (/ + /);
```

ReferenceError: The message is not defined

I'm not very good at javascript but I hope you will help me anyway.

My Index.js

```
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log("SETTE STELLE E' ONLINE MERDE")


const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
if(command === "clear"){
    
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
}
```

});

My clear.js

```
module.exports = {
name : "clear",
description: "Elimina merda",
async execute(message, args) {
    if(!args[0]) return message.reply("il mona non sa come fare un !clear. BRO DEVI DIRE IL NUMERO DI MESSAGGI");
    if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Certo, alla prossima apposto di un numero metti carciofo scem0");

    if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("Si vabbene 100.000 messaggi ok, MASSIMO 100 TESTA DI MERDA");
    if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("Alla prossima magari cancella almeno un messaggio");

    await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages =>{
        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
    })
}
```

}

Comment: First there is a typo in `const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);` it's `length`.

Comment: `message` does not exist in the ready event, the event fires when the bot has logged in. You should move your code inside the `'message'` event

Answer (score 1):

You need a [messageCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) event on your bot's client in order to get the messages sent in a channel.

Just like `ready`, make a new event called `messageCreate` which takes a `message` parameter.

So your **index.js** is going to be like this -

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("SETTE STELLE E' ONLINE MERDE")
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if(command === "clear"){
         client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    }
})
```

- I also noticed `prefix.lenght` in your code which should be `prefix.length`